# Dock Panel Hangs

Tags: dockpanel-suite

I am using WeifenLuo.WinFormsUI.Docking.dll(3.0.6 version ,Release Date-24/10/2018) in my project fro docking windows. When I got frequently live data in my docking child window and if want to undock that window from parent window my application freeze  and stuck at one place. I My application is in C#.net 4.5 framework.

Comment: You are supposed to debug the hang issue with tools like performance profile, hang dump analysis and so on.

Comment: Thank-you , I will  try this definitely .